# How to properly preprocess small tiles containing digits for tesseract OCR?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft7uE.png)

[Sample output cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkDLV.png)

Code:

> ```
>         if abs(averageArea - area) <= 0.15 * area:
>             cellImg = preprocess(img[y:y + h, x:x + w])
>             cell = Cell()
>             cell.x = x
>             cell.y = y
>             cell.w = w
>             cell.h = h
>             cell.content = pytesseract.image_to_string(cellImg).strip()
> ```

Console output:

> ```
> Row 0:  38h 38p
> Row 1:  38}
> Row 2:  38a 38C 38g
> ```

Preprocess function (only does resize atm after trying different methods):

> ```
> def preprocess(img):
>     img_resized = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=5, fy=5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
>     # tried gaussianblur and otsu bin after
>     return img_resized
> ```

However I can't seem to get the output right... however this site can: [Online OCR Tool](https://www.onlineocr.net/)

Their solution can't be other than generic, any suggestions/leads to what I'm doing wrong?

## Split input image into smaller cells to be able to distinguish from junk cells

## Enlarge smaller cells

## Applying various preprocessing methods before attempting OCR

Comment: why did you disfigure your question so? please review https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help -- [tour], [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking around with some preprocessing functions eventually led to an acceptable answer. Cudos to [@Christoph Rackwitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602877/christoph-rackwitz)

```
    def preprocess(img):
        #resize img for readability
        img_resized = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        # convert to gray
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # convert to black/white and filter out noise
        new_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 85, 30)

    return new_image
```